# How to change styling of nested elements without an id in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a chrome extension that changes the colors of websites to reduce eye strain. I have noticed that a lot of websites have tags without IDs or Classes. For instance:

```
<span>Insert Text Here</span>
```

In my code I will write

```
document.body.style.color = #fff;
```

and it changes most of the text color from black to white but nested elements aren't effected.

How would I make all the text colors white and all the background colors dark?

Comment: "It depends". Reading the CSS Selectors Level 3 specification would probably be useful.

Comment: show us some code ?

Comment: `body { filter: invert(100%); }`

Comment: I'd recommend asking this question again but providing a specific, code-based example of what you're trying to do and your own attempt at it.

Comment: @Cerbrus: LOL!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need **some** way of identifying the elements. That doesn't mean they have to have IDs or classes, you have [the full range of CSS selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) at your disposal for use in a `style` element you can add to the page from your extension's code. Or you can use those CSS selectors in JavaScript code using [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and apply additional logic if necessary.